# Table of surface Parametric draw

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry, parametric-functions, drawing, parameters

I'm trying to reproduce this kind of graph for a spherical cap, with different span ratios.
I tried with this:

```
TableForm@
 Table[Table[
   SphericalPlot3D[r, {\[Theta], 0, \[Theta]0}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Boxed -> False], {\[Theta]0, 0.1, Pi/2, Pi/7}], {r, 0.01, 1, 0.2}]
```

But the result is not what I hoped.
Does anyone have some suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
surf1[a_, b_] = 
  ContourPlot3D[
   y^2/a^2 + z^2/b^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     z^2/b^2 + x^2/a^2 >= 1 && z >= 0 && Abs[x] <= Min[a, b] && 
      Abs[y] <= Min[a, b]], PlotPoints -> 50, 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None];
surf2[a_, b_] = 
  ContourPlot3D[
   z^2/b^2 + x^2/a^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, 
     y^2/a^2 + z^2/b^2 >= 1 && z >= 0 && Abs[x] <= Min[a, b] && 
      Abs[y] <= Min[a, b]], PlotPoints -> 50, 
   RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None];
surf[a_, b_] := 
  Show[surf1[a, b], surf2[a, b], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False];
surfs = Table[surf[a, b], {a, 3, 5, .5}, {b, 3, 5, .5}];
Graphics3D[
 Table[GeometricTransformation[surfs[[i, j]][[1]], 
   TranslationTransform[15 {i, j, 0}]], {i, 
   Dimensions[surfs][[1]]}, {j, Dimensions[surfs][[2]]}], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> {True, True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your wonderful example. I'm trying to modify it for a spherical cap, can you give me any suggestions?  surf1[a_, b_] = 
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == a/b, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z >= 0], PlotPoints -> 50, 
   Mesh -> None];
surfs = Table[surf1[a, b], {a, 3, 5, .5}, {b, 3, 5, .5}];
Graphics3D[
 Table[GeometricTransformation[surfs[[i, j]][[1]], 
   TranslationTransform[5 {i, j, 0}]], {i, 
   Dimensions[surfs][[1]]}, {j, Dimensions[surfs][[2]]}], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> {True, True, False}]

Comment: @MatteoLai  Add `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None` to the `surf1[a,b]`

Comment: `RegionBoundaryStyle ` is a command that is not present in my Mathematica (version: 12). To run your code I must cancel it. Besides, it draws a cylindrical, not a spherical one.

Comment: @Matteo Lai that appears to be a separate question entirely that you should ask in a new post, linking to this one if needed; as it stands this question is seemingly answer successfully by this answer. Your Mathematica version is also essential to include in cases when you are not fully updated to the current version. When you ask your new question related to this region boundary problem, that is a necessary piece of information you should include.